# An exception occurred when the socket's descriptor was used for _get_osfhandle

Tags: windows, sockets, winapi, visual-c++

[image]

I don't know how to deal with this problem. please help me.
thanks

Comment: Check error codes of `WSAStartup` and `socket` (using `WSAGetLastError`)? (Also please don't post images, post text. If inevitable, embed the image)

Comment: You can copy *any* standard dialog as text into the clipboard, simply by pressing Ctrl+C. Also, source code is text already. Please supply text for either one.

Comment: Just because a Win32 `SOCKET` is defined as an (unsigned) integer type does not mean it represents a valid C file descriptor that you can pass to `_get_osfhandle()`. Because it is not. `_get_osfhandle()` only works with C file descriptors that wrap Win32 handles, such as from `_open_osfhandle()`. Just because the code compiles does not make it right. `_get_osfhandle(12345)` compiles, but clearly `12345` is not a valid file descriptor.

Comment: why are you calling _get_osfhandle(fd)? The call doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

According to [File-Handling Routines (File Descriptor)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/file-handling?view=msvc-170#file-handling-routines-file-descriptor), you need to first associate a C run-time file descriptor with an existing operating-system file handle ([`_open_osfhandle()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/open-osfhandle?view=msvc-170)), and then you can get the operating-system file handle associated with an existing C run-time file descriptor ([`_get_osfhandle()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/get-osfhandle?view=msvc-170)).

Like this:

```
int fd = _open_osfhandle(sock, 0);
intptr_t handle = _get_osfhandle(fd);
```

[image]

Comment: Sockets are not normal HANDLEs, this might somewhat work but who knows if it's a good idea.